# Div on top of another with Tailwind CSS

Tags: tailwind-css

How do I get the second inner div to be on top of the first inner div (map)? I can't figure this out, despite using relative & absolute positioning. I'm using React & Tailwind CSS. Instead, the second inner div currently follows the flow of the image and is positioned below the first children div.

```html
<div className="relative w-full h-screen">
  <div className="bg-green-400 w-full h-full z-0">
    <p className="italic text-bold bd-red-100 font-serif">Map</p>
  </div>
  <div className="absolute z-50">
    <p className="text-2xl font-bold">This should be on top of the map</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Here's a [Tailwind Play Code](https://play.tailwindcss.com/h0BmHTW9KQ) I created based on your query. I have tweaked height and width for proper visual.

```html
<div class="w-full h-screen bg-gray-200 flex justify-center items-center">
  <div class="bg-gray-400 w-96 h-96 relative z-0">
    <p class="italic text-bold bd-red-100 font-serif">Map</p>
    <div class="absolute inset-0 flex justify-center items-center z-10">
      <p class="text-2xl font-bold">This should be on top of the map</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

I would like to extend @Digvijay's answer further more to provide extended explanation, which consists

##### 1. `Logic`

##### 2. `Responsive Sidebar`

##### 3. `Responsive Sidebar with hamburger menu`

---

You'll have to work with `relative` `absolute` and `z-index` to make this work.

#### 1. Logic:

Have parent `relative` having `z-index` value less than the child `absolute` div which will be used for navbar.

#### Code:

```
    <div class="h-screen relative z-0 flex bg-gray-500">
      <div class="text-4xl">
        The main content of the file and it has it's content all over the page
        and i want to build a navbar on top of this
      </div>
      <div class="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 z-10 bg-green-400 w-1/3">
        <div class="flex h-full items-center justify-center text-4xl">
          Mobile Navbar
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

##### Output:

[image]

##### Code Link: [tailwind play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/gWk390mobZ)

---

### 2. Responsive Sidebar

If you are aiming to build `responsive sidebar` which overlaps only on the `mobile screen` but would be normal div in the `large screen` then follow the below code.

#### Code:

```
    <div class="md:bg-yellow-400 h-screen relative z-0 flex bg-gray-500">
      <div class="invisible md:visible bg-blue-400 w-1/3">
        <div class="flex h-full items-center justify-center text-4xl">
          Desktop Navbar
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="text-4xl">
        The main content of the file and it has it's content all over the page
        and i want to build a navbar on top of this
      </div>
      <div
        class="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 z-10 bg-green-400 w-1/3 md:invisible"
      >
        <div class="flex h-full items-center justify-center text-4xl">
          Mobile Navbar
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

##### Code link : [tailwind play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/N8yjIUHXVT)

#### Output in large device:

[image]

#### Output in smaller device:

[image]

---

### 3. Toggle mobile navbar using hamburger menu

#### Output on large devices

[image]

#### Output in small device with `hamburger menu`

[image: Enter description]

#### When clicked on `hamburger menu`

[image]

#### Code:

```
  <body>
    <div class="bg-yellow-400 h-screen relative z-0 flex">
      <div class="hidden md:block bg-blue-400 w-1/3">
        <div class="flex h-full items-center justify-center text-4xl">
          Desktop Navbar
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="text-4xl pl-24 md:p-0 main_content">
        The main content of the file and it has it's content all over the page
        and i want to build a navbar on top of this
      </div>
      <div
        class="mobile_navbar absolute inset-y-0 left-0 z-10 bg-green-400 w-1/3 hidden md:hidden"
      >
        <div class="flex h-full items-center justify-center text-4xl">
          Mobile Navbar
        </div>
      </div>
      <div
        class="md:hidden space-y-2 absolute hamburger_menu inset-y-0 left-0 p-4"
      >
        <span class="block w-8 h-1 bg-white"></span>
        <span class="block w-8 h-1 bg-white"></span>
        <span class="block w-8 h-1 bg-white"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document
        .querySelector(".hamburger_menu")
        .addEventListener("click", () => {
          console.log("Hello");
          document.querySelector(".mobile_navbar").classList.toggle("hidden");
        });

      document.querySelector(".main_content").addEventListener("click", () => {
        console.log("Touch me");
        console.log(
          document
            .querySelector(".mobile_navbar")
            .classList.contains("hidden") == false &&
            document.querySelector(".mobile_navbar").classList.toggle("hidden")
        );
      });
    </script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 2):

There's another straightforward way of doing this with Tailwind: Define a grid container but give the grid cells the same placement.

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="col-start-1 row-start-1">
    A
  </div>
  <div class="col-start-1 row-start-1">
    B
  </div>
</div>
```

This will place the characters 'A' and 'B' on top of each other.