# How to overlap a div over a div in tailwind-css

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have a navbar on my site, when the site is on mobile size I want to have my hamburger menu overlap the contents of my page.

This is my site :

```
<!-- logo Start -->
<div class="nav-logo">
  <h1>My site</h1>
</div>

<!-- links Start -->
<div
  class=
    "
    w-full
    flex
    flex-col
    items-center
    text-5xl
    md:pr-20
    "

>
  <a href="#"
     class="block md:inline-block">Work</a>
  <a href="#"
     class="block md:inline-block">About</a>
  <a href="#"
     class="block md:inline-block">Contact</a>
<div/>

    <!-- links End -->

  </nav>

    <main>
    <article>
     <h1>Hello<h1/>
    </article>
    <main/>
```

I tried adding `relative` and `z-10` both on my `nav-links` and `nav` but they dont work, they still push the content downwards instead of having that div overlap.

Any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Div on top of another with Tailwind CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65749715/div-on-top-of-another-with-tailwind-css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to work with `relative` `absolute` and `z-index` to make this work.

#### Logic:

Have parent `relative` having `z-index` value less than the child `absolute` div which will be used for navbar.

#### Output in large device:

[image]

#### Output in smaller device:

[image]

#### Code:

```
    <div class="md:bg-yellow-400 h-screen relative z-0 flex bg-gray-500">
      <div class="invisible md:visible bg-blue-400 w-1/3">
        <div class="flex h-full items-center justify-center text-4xl">
          Desktop Navbar
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="text-4xl">
        The main content of the file and it has it's content all over the page
        and i want to build a navbar on top of this
      </div>
      <div
        class="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 z-10 bg-green-400 w-1/3 md:invisible"
      >
        <div class="flex h-full items-center justify-center text-4xl">
          Mobile Navbar
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Further more you can use this [tailwind play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/N8yjIUHXVT) link

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74981134/13431819) for responsive sidebar with / without hamburger menu